# installing elementaryOS on Snow Leopard: best alternative for Etcher

Tags: system-installation, macbook, usb-drive

the title pretty much says it all, I'd like to know the safest alternative to etcher for this installation process on Snow Leopard. Elementary os guide says one should use etcher but etcher needs os x 10.9 or newer.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I used unetbootin on Windows. I hope this help : https://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna burn it on a friend's pc and I'll try that program. Thank you!!

Comment: Wait a minute: If you just want to install using a CD/DVD, you only need to burn the .iso file into a CD. Tools like etcher or unetbootin are used to make a USB storage unit bootable.